# Unable to get HTTP/HTTPS response

Tags: windows

I am testing the HTTP/HTTPS connection from server to client via a command 'telnet <IP/hostname> port (80)', but I am getting an error message that 'could not open connection to the host, on port 80: connection failed'. My server and client systems are installed in the same network and connected with same switch. No VLAN also configured between them. Please help me on the same to resolve the issue.

Disabled all local firewalls in the systems

Comment: You did not add your code.